# Is there a way to change the thickness and color of the curves in the plot using wireframe of lattice in R?

Tags: r, plot, lattice, wireframe

I am using the wireframe in lattice package of R to plot a 3D data.
I think it is because there're too many data points so the plot looks a little messy.

Is there a way to make the connecting curves (between the yellow and red blocks) in the plot more of light color or thinner?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the lines, but I think the width is already minimal. Here is an example:

```
wireframe(volcano, drape =T, col="grey",
      aspect = c(61/87, 0.4),
      light.source = c(10,0,10))
```

[image]